# Cannot rate apps on Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

I just found out I cannot rate apps on Google play. Any app. And yes, I have them installed. But the rating 5 stars or 'Rate' button are missing.

Am I missing something? Anyone else experiencing the same issue or know why is this happening / How to overcome this?

Comment: Were those apps sideloaded or updated without Play Store?

Comment: I have had this issue for many years on my "apps for business" Google account (or whatever they're calling it these days). No solution in sight.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quite weird, but looks like this is happening because I'm a G Suite user.
When I switch to a different, regular gmail address user, I can rate my apps again.

Looks like this behavior is rather new and undocumented (started around June 2018).

I found this article: [G Suite users can't review or rate Play Store content anymore](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/06/22/g-suite-users-cant-review-rate-play-store-content-anymore/).
But haven't found any official evidence from Google to support that.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be exactly what's happening. Google docs [say](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4346705): `You can only review apps you've previously downloaded and installed. When you download an app, it's linked to your Google Account. If you downloaded the app but don't see the option to write a review, make sure you're signed in to the right account.` But that's incorrect, I installed the app with a G Suite account -no review available- and changed to another Gmail account and it let's me write the review.

Answer (score 6):

Try the workaround below.
 I found this trick mentioned in one of the support threads that Google
 stubbornly ignore

1. Go to the Play Store page for the app you want to rate, e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand
2. Copy the app ID (after ?id=) from the URL bar - here that is:
   net.osmand
3. Go to https://play.google.com/store/ereview?docId=, adding the copied
   ID: https://play.google.com/store/ereview?docId=net.osmand
4. You should now see a blank page with a small text box in the middle.
5. Just write your review and click Submit. You can then edit or delete
   the review the usual way, from the store page.

Comment: Not working any more

Comment: Did just work for me; March 2023

Comment: @Erhannis Were you able to see your review afterwards?

Comment: @plu Yup; if I go to the app in the Play Store app, I can see my review.  I don't know whether other people see it, but I'd assume so.

Comment: @Erhannis I tried the method and pressed "submit"; it greyed out and didn't give any confirmation that the review was submitted. I also could not see any such review on the review section of the app, even after a couple of weeks. Perhaps it is still related to my account being a "G Suite" one; I tried with a different non-G-Suite account and there were no problems.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue JUST sign out of your Google account on your phone (remove account), restart your phone, and then sign in to your google account again. (It might also work without restarting your phone.)

To do this, go to settings, user accounts. (On different devices these names might be a bit different.)

Comment: I'm able to switch accounts right from the play store.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my phone and the problem was gone. It seems the problems roots are from the G+ extermination. Some accounts were affected in this regard. You don't need to delete and then add your account again; it's more like a re-login and since every time you restart your phone you login with your credentials is enough.

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried it multiple times.