# Cannot rate some installed apps on Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

It looks like I can rate some apps on Google Play store and cannot for some other ones while both are installed on my smartphone.

Here are two examples.

1. InShot app is installed on my phone. But, Google Play Store does not list it under Installed tab. And it is not allowing me to rate or review this app.
   [image: inshot app on play store]
2. Kinemaster app is listed under Installed tab and I can give it rating.
   [image]

I tried all the solutions in the question [Cannot rate apps on Google Play](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207384/335883). But, these aren't working.

This issue exists with quite a few of the apps on my device. So, why isn't Google Play Store allowing me to rate some installed apps? Is there any solution?

EDIT: From this [Google Play thread](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/14104301?hl=en), it looks like many people faced the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Also happening with my application also,
I am not sure but I checked it's happening on my company email, Google has an algorithm in which you can't rate your company app OR you can not rate the app with an organization account but with my personal account I can rate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think Google is purposely screening our reviews, I've seen apps where every review read claims the app is a scam but still has a 4.5-star rating. I have come across maybe 10 apps that have over 50k downloads but no reviews and even though, I found the app to be nothing but a scam ADWARE, and didn't work, Google would not allow me to leave a review.

[image: this app for example of the Viera TV remote]

Comment: I think one of the big problems with the Google ecosystem, and the Google Play store in particular, is that (like Amazon), it is plagued by fake reviews by scammers.  And, like Amazon, Google does not take sufficient action to deal with the scammers.  What happened when you tried to leave the review for Google Play store app that was obviously a scam?

Comment: F-Droid (https://f-droid.org) is a well regarded source for quality open-source apps.  Unlike Google, they have an effective system in place for preventing scam software.  And unlike Google, which is worth over a trillion USD, F-Droid operates on a shoestring budget.  That should tell you quite a bit about the priorities and values of the questionable people at Google vs. the good people at F-Droid.